# leiningen and counterclockwise dependencies issue

Tags: clojure, leiningen, incanter, counterclockwise

I got the following Error while using counterclockwise an Eclipse Ide for Clojure and leiningen

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Leiningen Managed Dependencies issue: problem resolving following dependencies: [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT"]   project.clj /IncanterExamples   line 1  Leiningen Classpath Container
```

By clicking on Project.clj -> leiningen -> update dependencies

```
(defproject IncanterExamples "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
    :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
        [incanter "1.5.4"]])
```

Comment: Recreating your project.clj I don't get any issues. Checking the leiningen deps there is no entry for clojure-contrib (as expected, that's been replaced a loooong time ago).

Comment: Sorry - forgot to say - ccw version is 0.23.0.STABLE001. I'll see if upgrading to 24.2 might break and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Running 0.24.2.STABLE001 works perfectly too. Chalking this one up and moving on, my http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/ certification in hand.

Comment: counterclockwise runs under Eclipse Java EE IDE Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627 and Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_51 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM. I also check "Help -> check for updates" but no updates were found.

Comment: as soon I removed from another project [incanter "1.2.2"] and replaced it by [incanter "1.5.4"] all projects started to work.

Comment: Here's a "me too": I have the same error message using CCW0.28.0.STABLE001, with a project.clj containing _no_ dependencies other than clojure 1.6.0. I found your question hoping to find a solution.